# If condition in python in a loop

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas

I am facing difficulty with the correct syntax of the if condition. I want to apply the condition to check the equality of a string. But the way i am trying to do it, is giving me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'any'
for :
for a in prod_comm:
    if prod_comm['label']==('label":"neg"}').any():
        prod_pos.append(a)
```

or :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
for :
for a in prod_comm:
    if prod_comm.label==('label":"neg"}'):
        prod_neg.append(a)
```

What I am trying to do is:
have a dataframe with 2 columns- c and label. I want to divide this dataframe into different files based on the type of label, which is either:

```
label":"neg"}    or     label":"pos"}
```

How may i go forward with the classification? I guess there is an issue with the syntax i am using, but can't find the correct syntax on the net.

```
Example dataset:
        comment                                  label
    0   need 3 bhk house                         "label": "neg"}
    2   tried to list my property                "label": "neg"}
    22  i have issue with the map                "label": "neg"}
    24  also help with the rental agreements     "label": "pos"}
    37  sort option should be available.         "label": "pos"}

expected output:
two datasets:
prod_pos - with the comments corresponding to label: "label": "pos"}
prod_neg - with the comments corresponding to label: "label": "neg"}
i.e. 

prod_pos:
    comment                                  label
24  also help with the rental agreements     "label": "pos"}
37  sort option should be available.         "label": "pos"}

prod_neg:
        comment                                  label
    0   need 3 bhk house                         "label": "neg"}
    2   tried to list my property                "label": "neg"}
    22  i have issue with the map                "label": "neg"}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post representative data, code, errors and desired output that others can run, thanks

Comment: `('label":"neg"}').any()` - you explicitly stated that `.any()` should be called on `'label":"neg"}'`. Please reconsider usage of parenthesis.

Comment: I did try using it without the parenthesis. It still gave the same error note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a pandas dataframe, so can just do this:

Given your dataframe:

```
df
                                comment          label
0                      need 3 bhk house  label: "neg"}
1             tried to list my property  label: "neg"}
2             i have issue with the map  label: "neg"}
3  also help with the rental agreements  label: "pos"}
4      sort option should be available.  label: "pos"}
```

Just do:

```
df_neg = df[df.label=='label: "neg"}']
df_pos = df[df.label=='label: "pos"}']
```

Which gives:

```
df_neg
                     comment          label
0           need 3 bhk house  label: "neg"}
1  tried to list my property  label: "neg"}
2  i have issue with the map  label: "neg"}

df_pos
                                comment          label
3  also help with the rental agreements  label: "pos"}
4      sort option should be available.  label: "pos"}
```

HTH